# Reordering & hiding tabs in angular 2 using QueryList

Tags: angular, typescript, tabs, hide, reorderlist

There are 2 tabs (TabA and TabB) resulting from the TabsComponent below.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tabs',
  template:
  `
        <ul class="tab-nav">
            <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs" (click)="selectTab(tab)" [class.active]="tab.active">
                {{tab.title}} 
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    `
})
export class TabsComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren(TabComponent) tabs: QueryList<TabComponent>;
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    let activeTabs = this.tabs.filter((tab) => tab.active);
    if (activeTabs.length === 0) {
      this.selectTab(this.tabs.first);
    }
  }
  selectTab(tab: TabComponent) {
    this.tabs.toArray().forEach(tab => tab.active = false);
    tab.active = true;
    this.onTabSelect.emit(tab);
  }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'tab',
    template:
    `
        <div class="tab-content">
           <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>
    `
})
export class TabComponent {
    @Input('tabTitle') title: string;
    @Input() active = false;    
}
```

There are three tab selection scenarios driven by radios:
1) Display both tabs with TabA selected by default
2) Display TabA when link A was clicked, Tab B should be hidden
3) Display TabB when link B was clicked, Tab A should be hidden

As tabs are contained in QueryList, there are no methods that can reorder/sort the tab. Also tried converting QueryList toArray and then sort it by the selected tab it did not work.

Would appreciate your guidance.

Comment: having similar issue and can't find a way to get an updated list of QueryList without hacking Elements.